# Suitable tense for specific time

Tags: grammar, tense

I understand that when we use the past continuous tense, our listener usually understands what time we are talking about. Like, "I was working at 10 pm last night."

However, I saw a sentence in a textbook it wrote that "I was in bed asleep at 4.30 this morning."  I wonder why it didn't use past continuous tense; can we say "I was being in bed asleep at 4.30 this morning" or not?  Plus, I'm not sure if the verb *to be* can be continuous or not for this case.

Moreover for verbs that can't be continuous, if I write a specific time, I have to use past tense not continuous tense, right? For example, "I saw a very big bird at 10 am this morning."  Is it correct to use past tense "saw" in this case?

Answer (score 6):

Right, as you say, when we use the past continuous tense there is usually some context that makes it clear to the reader / listener when the event was happening. Your question seems to be mostly about [stative verbs](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html) (1) to be; and (2) to see.

**(1) Be**

Verbs that are not typically used in continuous tenses are called *stative*. Examples are see, be, want, hear. So we say "*I was in bed...*" not "*I was being...*". There are some cases when stative verbs like ["be" are used in a continuous tense](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_vmwct_3.htm) and these cases tend to change the meaning of the verb.

**(2) See**

As to the correctness of "*I saw a very big bird at 10am this morning*", this will depend on the context. It is a grammatically correct sentence; it appropriately expresses the idea that at 10am a bird appeared in view.

However, if you wanted to express some kind of continuous observation then you would need a different verb, not *see* (which is stative). E.g. you might say, "when someone knocked on the door at 10am *I was watching* a big bird".

Comment: +1 Did you drop the word "stative" from the end of the first sentence of your second paragraph?

Comment: See is sometimes stative, sometimes not. "I was seeing a bird" is not correct. "I was seeing a woman" could be. "I saw a woman" is also grammatical and could be either meaning of "see".

Comment: @PeterFlom Yes; I think that's what Jon meant when he said that sometimes they are used in a continuous tense but it usually changes the meaning :) +1!

Comment: Thank you everyone. And thanks a lot Jon for your explanations, It is so useful and helpful. Ah, it 's called stative verbs. Your explanations and that website really help me and it's easy to understand. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @PeterFlom- But if someone asked me, "When you were looking through the binoculars what were you seeing?" I'd reply, "I was seeing a bird."

Comment: @jim That sounds a little awkward to me, but I don't think it's wrong.